# Force a specific arrangement of virtual and non virtual base classes

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, abi, memory-layout, vptr

If I have a code like this:

```
class A {
public:
    int data1;
}

class B {
public:
    virtual void test() {}
}

class C : public A, public B {
    int data2;
}
```

and when I now create an instance of C its memory layout looks something like this:

```
B::vtable
A::data1
C::data2
```

but what I actually want is something like this:

```
A::data1
B::vtable
C::data2
```

Is there some kind of keyword to force the inheritance order?

Is use VC++15 to compile, and what the problem is that I use a big autogenerated code base which uses for all classes void* pointers to "fake" the vtables... now I use that code base and inherit it, this instances now need a special order of memory layouts to work correctly with a different framework to load. And that framework needs the A data at the front.

Comment: You'll need to specify what environment you're working in (OS & compiler), this is not specified in standard C++

Comment: Why is the order important to you?

Comment: ***Why?*** What is the problem you have that rearranging the data like that will solve?

Comment: Please tell us what are you trying to achieve. I don't believe that there is a portable solution to this.

Comment: Is use VC++15 to compile, and what the problem is that I use a big autogenerated code base which uses for all classes void* pointers to "fake" the vtables... now I use that code base and inherit it, this instances now need a special order of memory layouts to work correctly with a different framework to load. And that framework needs the B data at the front.

Comment: Why do you write "vtable"? Instance don't have a vtable in them.

Comment: "_which uses for all classes void* pointers to "fake" the vtables... now I use that code base and inherit it,_" It would help if you could show the relevant part of that code and explain the exact assumptions that are made here.